# FBML in Rails views using Facebooker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, fbml, facebooker

I have successfully wired up a Facebook Connect application and everything is working fine.  I can sign new users up with Facebook, or I can link existing users with Facebook.  No problems there.

However, now I am trying to add an Invite page, where a user can see which of their Friends have the application, and then show them a Facebook FMBL Multi Select form to invite friends into it.

Here is the documentation for that FBML tag.

http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Connect/Integrating_an_Invite_Form_into_Your_Website#Creating_a_Full_Multi-friend_Selector_Request_or_Invite

However, I cannot get this to work **within** my Rails view.

Do I need to setup something special to use FBML in my Rails views?

THIS IS NOT A CANVAS Application, meaning I want people to come to my site and not visit the page through facebook, but I feel like I am missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you develop a facebook connect site, it uses XFBML. XFBML for Facebook connect and iframe applications and FBML for facebook canvas applications. And, facebook multi-friend-selector is FBML tag.

But, you can call FBML inside of XFBML, so you should check this page.

> http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Fb:serverFbml

this could help.

Comment: Thanks for this.  It was helpful, however it is still now working.  Certain elements work really well, but the fb:request-form does not.
According to their API, it could be because they are changing this section of the API.

Answer (score 1):

Your doctype should include the FBML namespace & you should be loading the featureload.js.php script, see: http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Connect/Setting_Up_Your_Site#Rendering_XFBML_and_Other_Facebook_Connect_Features

Comment: Thanks for this.  I am doing this, however I think the problem might be in the underlying API.  the fb:request-form is one of the only tags that I can't get working.